# How to limit Phusion Passenger memory usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, phusion

Is there a way to limit the amount of memory Phusion Passenger uses when serving up your app?

My host comes by and kills the process after I get a bunch of traffic and so I end up serving up blank pages. Is there anything I can do to say "hey don't use any more than 100Mb and only spawn 3 processes no matter how overloaded the site is"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to limit the memory usage explicitly (say use <= 100MiB).

But what you can do is limit the number of processes by setting [PassengerMaxPoolSize](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMaxPoolSize). 
Set that and then see how is the memory usage (that depends on the apps you are running).

Also, using [Ruby Enterprise Edition](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/) may help.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is no-longer true (in 2015). If you are using Passenger Enterprise 5.0+ you can set PassengerMemoryLimit: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengermemorylimit

Comment: This actually won't help because you need more servers rather then more memory on this server. Its like an equation where you have to decide what to optimize: response time or costs

Answer (score 2):

Also check out passenger_max_requests, new in 3.0.11

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMaxRequests

Answer (score 0):

appears it may have been "implemented in passenger enterprise" https://code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=201

Answer (score 0):

To complement what Mihai A wrote in 2009, [REE has reached end of life in 2012](http://blog.phusion.nl/2012/02/21/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-2012-02-released-end-of-life-imminent/). One of the main reasons being that it does not offer a significant performance improvment over Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, the Enterprise version of passenger has this feature.

For the free version, check out this blog post: http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2012/08/simple-rubyrails-passenger-memory-consumption-limit-monitoring/

Answer (score -4):

Try running it in a Solaris Zone ;)

Comment: awn -1. "Change to another platform" should be always a very evident or very argumented answer